# Clarifications on my update techniques and possibly easier ways to do it

Tags: database, codeigniter, sql-update

An updated version of how i can update/edit my rows. Instead of making a page to view all the rows and making a link to another page whch then we can input there what rows to update. I have formulated this.

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Crud Functions - Bookshelf</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="header">
        <div>

        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="body">
        <div>
            <div>
                <div>
                    <div class="programs">
                        <h2>Book Options:</h2>
                        <div class="first">
                            <ul>
                                <li class="selected">
                                    <a href="showbooks">View Books</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="showinsert">Add Book</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="showupdate">Update Book</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="showdelete">Delete Book</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                        <div>

<?php echo form_open('bookstore/update'); ?>
<table  cellpadding='5'>

<th>Update</th>
<th>Book ID</th>
<th>Title</th>
<th>Author</th>
<th>Released Year</th>
<th>ISBN</th>

<?php

if(isset($books)) : foreach($books as $book) :
?>      
        <tr>
        <td><input type="submit" name="idtoupdate" value="<?=$book['book_id']?>"/></td>
        <td><?php echo $book['book_id'] ?></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="bkname" value="<?php echo $book['book_name'] ?>"/></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="bkauthor" value="<?php echo $book['book_author'] ?>"/></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="bkyear" value="<?php echo $book['book_year'] ?>"/></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="bkisbn" value="<?php echo $book['book_isbn'] ?>"/></td>
        </tr>
<?php
    endforeach;
?>
<?php
else :
?>
<h5>No records</h5>
<?php
endif;
?>
</table>
<?php echo form_close();?>


                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

So far it works. Although i dont know if i could update multiple rows at the same time or that would require more coding. But ill try, this is one way for me to learn to try and seek a better and faster way of doing things.

Comment: not in the right direction bro !! :(

Comment: How come? anything wrong? could you point it out so i could practice proper way of coding.

I see, the problem is that i used text boxes and instead of a submit button i used link.. although i can just put in a submit button in the middle of the link right?

or i could just use a form. Ill revise it later.. im still waiting for more clarifications.. Im always eager to learn from professionals :)

Comment: dont use base_url to prepare link let CI do it for you with <?php echo anchor('controller/functionname/' . $param_here,'Display Text'); ?>

Comment: Ive had troubles using the anchor method when i tried the deletion of rows wherein the passed value was the parameter that i wrote instead of the value it contained although it could be just me or some configurations i havent made. Im still learning so i guess time is my friend.

Comment: Quick question,

i dont know what the boolean parameter true means in this statement:
$name = $this->input->post('bkname', TRUE);

Answer (score 0):

Start of by asking yourself why you use a framework. I use it to easen everything up and take use of the [documentation](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/) and [practices](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/styleguide.html). Once you realize the point of a framework, you'll learn to use it better.

Inside the html, consider using:

```
<? if (TRUE): ?>
Print this
<? endif; ?>
```

Rather than:

```
<? if (TRUE) { ?>
Print this
<? } ?>
```

For more readability when mixing in HTML aswell.

Instead of:

```
$name = $this->input->xss_clean($this->input->post('bkname'));
```

use:

```
$name = $this->input->post('bkname', TRUE);
```

[It's the same effect](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/input.html).

---

That said, try simply to make code that's simple and logical. Always adjust your styling and approaches towards what you know/think would be simplier and logical. If there's a part of your code you dislike, try rebuilding it and compare the differences.

CodeIgniter goes by the [MVC principle](http://sv.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model-View-Controller). It means to split up the visuals, the commands and the common actions into different parts of your code. Don't fetch data inside a view file, avoid echoing html inside a controller for instance.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I already understand the concept of MVC. Model View Controller. 

The thing is, Im a college student, i went from simple procedural programming style.. to using OOP then to mvc. Each sembreak or summer i dont practice coding and i always end up forgetting most of the syntax thats why im always asking if im doing it right.. Though things have changed now. im graduating this year so im doing my best to maximize my study habits.

Ill keep that in mind.

Comment: May i ask the use of : though?

does it eliminate the use of { } in every function?

Comment: I have updated my code, ill update my above post.. please tell me if im doing the codes properly.. because sometimes there are proper ways of doing it and improper ways and i want to practice the proper way of coding

Comment: It's easier to spot the php relations when it's mixed with php code through `:`. Looking at your update, you're supposed to have the HTML in view files which are included from the controller. The controller should send the values to the view. [Read up on it](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/views.html)

Answer (score 0):

You're making this way too difficult on yourself. Use the form helpers, don't even bother passing the book id in the URL (not best practice since you could technically write a script to overwrite every book in the database if you're doing it that way)

You want to create a form for each tr, pass the book_id as a hidden form variable then handle it in the controller.

HTML Snippet

```
<?php echo form_open('index.php/bookstore/update/'); ?>
<tr>
<td><?php echo $book['book_id']; echo form_hidden('book_id', $book['book_id']; ?></td>
<td><input type="text" name="bkname" value="<?php echo $book['book_name'] ?>"/></td>
<td><input type="text" name="bkauthor" value="<?php echo $book['book_author'] ?>"/></td>
<td><input type="text" name="bkyear" value="<?php echo $book['book_year'] ?>"/></td>
<td><input type="text" name="bkisbn" value="<?php echo $book['book_isbn'] ?>"/></td>
<td><?php echo form_submit('submitMe', 'Submit') ;?></td>
</tr>
<?php echo form_close() ;?>

public function update() 
{
    if ($this->input->post('submit'))       
    {
    $data['book_id'] = $this->input->post('book_id',TRUE);
    $data['name'] = $this->input->post('bkname', TRUE);
    $data['author'] = $this->input->post('bkauthor',TRUE);
    $data['year'] = $this->input->post('bkyear',TRUE);
    $data['isbn'] = $this->input->post('bkisbn',TRUE);
    //You really want to be doing some validation before running the update!!!
    $this->posts_model->updatePost($data);


            $this->load->view('showupdate');
    } 
}
```

To be honest you could even do the update directly from the controller (although some may consider that bad practice) by doing this:

```
 $this->db->update('books',$data);
```